# Extract values from string in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm extracting possible values from a description field in Oracle. There are thousands of them and I thought of doing it using SQL.

The issue is possible values are embedded in the description after the word "Acceptable values:" OR "Acceptable value:"

Also, the values have code and description, for ex.

00=No code

01=Additional code

I need the possible values extracted.

This is in Oracle table.

This is the source table:

Table1

```
VAR_NAME    VAR_DESC
Test 1      Code identifying test 1
            Acceptable values:
            00=No code
            01=Additional Code

Test 2      Code identifying test 2
            Acceptable value:
            44=No code
```

This is the output table:

```
VAR_NAME    VAR_DESC                    CODE        DESCRIPTION
Test 1      Code identifying test 1     00          No code
            Acceptable values:
            00=No code
            01=Additional Code

Test 1      Code identifying test 1     01          Additional Code
            Acceptable values:
            00=No code
            01=Additional Code


Test 2      Code identifying test 2     44          No code
            Acceptable value:
            44=No code
```

Is there a way in Oracle to extract this kind of information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_count` and `regexp_instr` together. The critical characters are `=` and carriage return (`chr(10)`) as in the following :

```
with table1(var_name,var_desc) as
(
 select 'Test 1',
        'Code identifying test 1
         Acceptable values:
         00=No code
         01=Additional Code' from dual union all
 select 'Test 2',
        'Code identifying test 2
         Acceptable value:
         44=No code'         from dual union all
 select 'Test 3',
        'Code identifying test 3' 
                             from dual       
), table2(var_name,str1,description) as
(
 select var_name,
        case when regexp_count(var_desc,chr(10)) > 0 then
             regexp_substr(var_desc,'[^=]+',regexp_instr(var_desc,chr(10), 1, level))
        end,
        case when regexp_count(var_desc,chr(10)) > 0 then
             regexp_substr(var_desc,'=(.*)+',regexp_instr(var_desc,chr(10), 1, level))
        end 
   from table1
connect by level <= regexp_count(var_desc,chr(10)) 
    and prior var_name = var_name
    and prior sys_guid() is not null   
)    
select t1.*, 
      decode(regexp_count(str1,chr(10)),1,str1) as code, ltrim(str1,'=') as description
 from table2 t2
 join table1 t1 on t1.var_name = t2.var_name
where decode(regexp_count(str1,chr(10)),1,str1) is not null
order by t1.var_name, code;

VAR_NAME    VAR_DESC                 CODE   DESCRIPTION
--------    -----------------------  ----   -----------
Test 1      Code identifying test 1  00     No code
            Acceptable values:
            00=No code
            01=Additional Code

Test 1      Code identifying test 1  01     Additional Code
            Acceptable values:
            00=No code
            01=Additional Code

Test 2      Code identifying test 2  44     No code
            Acceptable value:
            44=No code
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/FLXUS92036)</kbd>

Comment: I'm getting the following error: ORA-01428: argument '0' is out of range
01428. 00000 -  "argument '%s' is out of range"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @dang Hi, Dhananjay. Actually, I shared the demo, and works fine. Didn't you try?

Comment: Yes. The demo works. However, when I run on my table, it gives me this error. Not sure why.

Comment: @dang try to issue `SQL>alter session set  "_disable_function_based_index" = TRUE;` before calling the query.

Comment: I tried, but same error. Is it this problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46583627/getting-error-argument-0-is-out-of-range

Comment: If the first description has - select 'Test 1',
            'Code identifying test 1' from dual union all, then it throws the error.

Comment: @dang during this time interval, I was trying, and explored that yes you have some single line records for `var_desc` column, and issue stems from those columns. So, I added the constrint `case when regexp_count(var_desc,chr(10)) > 0 then...`

Comment: Sure thing, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

One of doing this is using the string functions. Here's a sample approach with the explanation.

```
with source_table as (select 
'Code identifying test 1
Acceptable values:
00=No code
01=Additional Code'  val
from dual)
select substr(val, instr(val, chr(10), 1, 2)+1 ,2) code
,substr(val, instr(val, '=', instr(val,chr(10), 1, 2), 1)+1 ,  (  instr(val,chr(10), 1, 3) - instr(val,'=', 1, 1)  ) ) description
from source_table;
```

Explanation

Step 1: Creating a table with data: Instead of actually creating a temporary table and adding the test data in, I'm spoofing the creation of a table using the **WITH** clause. In this case, I created a table with name **source_table** having one column **val**. It has one row of data which is the value in **VAR_DESC** column from row 1 of your source_table. You would not need to do this bit as you already have a table with data in your database.

```
with source_table as (select 
'Code identifying test 1
Acceptable values:
00=No code
01=Additional Code'  val
from dual)
```

Now for the actual string extraction. **INSTR** locates the position of a sub-string within a string. **SUBSTR** extracts a substring from within a string. So what I've done is, I've tried to identify a pattern in your data. The first data point to be extracted comes after the second **newline (chr(10))** character. Once I had this position, I exracted a substring of length 2 from this point. The next sub-string to be extracted begins after the first **=** character and has a length which has been computed as the difference of the position of the 4th **newline** character from the first **=** character.

Similarly if you have multiple rows of strings that need to be extracted within the same row of source data, you need to apply similar logic.

An easier way to do it would be to leverage Oracle's PL/SQL capabilities and create a function (which internally breaks the string apart in steps) and then invoke the function in the SQL. The code can be made much more readable. You would use the same string functions within PL/SQL. But you can do it steps making the code easier to follow for someone else who might need to manage your code later on.

Comment: Is there a way to extract all the codes available in the string separated by "=" and new line in 1 SQL query?